# What are the benefits of using Tmux at all times?

Tags: bash, terminal, osx, tmux

I have been using the terminal for all of my local work, and have only been using tmux when I am ssh'd onto another machine and want to make sure I don't lose work if the connection closes. A software engineer friend of mine says that he runs tmux for everything, including locally. What are the benefits of doing this?

Comment: I asked what the benefits of doing this were, not whether one method is better than another. Is that still too broad/do you have a suggestion of how I can pare it down so that it won't be closed?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't close this question on the ground of being *too broad*. Myself I could give several reasons for using screen/tmux all the time.